# Eagle Eye Mouse and Keyboard Converter for Multiple Players?

Tags: ps3

The Eagle Eye can be used to add mouse and keyboard support to your PS3. I want to know if it is possible to hook up multiple Eagle Eyes to ones PS3 so that multiple players can benefit from mouse and keyboard gameplay? I know it normally isn't possible to play games using multiple keyboards on a PC unless you individually map different key commands for each player, but I suspect that such configuration may not be necessary since the Eagle Eye uses the keyboard (and mouse) as a virtualized control rather than a 'true' keyboard like a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply get a USB multiplier and plug in all the ports correctly to the multiplier and you can connect X number of keyboards and mice. (This should work in theory, I use a USB multiplier to connect my charger and headset because on eof my USB ports are broken and it works them both fine, very little lag time for an inexpensive item.)

Comment: A USB hub does indeed appear to work, according to: https://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS3-Support/Any-issues-connecting-USB-hub-to-PlayStation-3/td-p/16901824